# What are the constants in this formula for polytrophic head?

Tags: regression, optimization, linear-programming

Polytrophic head can be expressed as H = b1N^2 + b2NQ + b3Q^2 where b1, b2 and b3 are constants, N is the speed of the compressor (rmp), and Q is the volumetric flow rate of natural gas at the compressor inlet (m3/s).

I am trying to understand where I get the values for constants in the above formula. I can find columns in a database for the speed of a compressor (N) and the flow rate of natural gas (Q), however how do I come up with the data for b1, b2 and b3? Do I just assign random values within some distribution, regression problem, etc? Thanks.

Source: Page Four of https://www.mdpi.com/1996-1073/15/15/5720/pdf

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very aware of this matter, but since you know that [image]

can't you just create 3 variables $H_1, H_2, H_3$ with random parameters and than doing a system of equations with $b_1, b_2, b_3$ as constants?